# Can a <FORM> submit radio-button's <LABEL> as VALUE?

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

We currently use the following syntax for radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" id="opt1" name="option" value="opt1" required/>
<label for="opt1">Description of Option One</label>
<input type="radio" id="opt2" name="option" value="opt2" required/>
<label for="opt2">Description of Option Two</label>
```

The query-processing script receives the string `"opt1"`, which it then needs to convert to the full-text description of the option. In PHP-speak, I get:

```
 $_POST['option'] => "opt1"
```

I'd like to save that step and have the full text of the description to be submitted as the value:

```
 $_POST['option'] => "Description of Option One"
```

Can this be done with HTML alone -- without resorting to JavaScript-rewriting hacks and without *duplicating* the description text in the HTML? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

**If you have control over the form**, the best solution is to use the description for the value:

```
<input type="radio" id="opt1" name="option" value="Description of Option One" required/>
<label for="opt1">Description of Option One</label>
<input type="radio" id="opt2" name="option" value="Description of Option Two" required/>
<label for="opt2">Description of Option Two</label>
```

**If you don't have control over the form**, then javascript is your only solution, you could use a function like the below (either inside an `onload` event for the page or an `onsubmit` event on the form:

```
function radioUpdate() {
  document.querySelectorAll('radio').forEach(function(input) {
    input.value = document.querySelector('label[for="' + input.id + '"]').text();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it can't.

Consider generating the HTML from your server side code in the first place. You could write a PHP function that takes the label/value as a single argument.

Comment: I don't want to generate the form for each request -- that loads the server and makes the result hard to cache. Many fewer people actually submit anything to the form-processor, than look at the form -- so the latter should be static, if at all possible.

Comment: "that loads the server" — A basic PHP script will have no significant impact on the server. CPU is very rarely a bottleneck this century. "makes the result hard to cache" — You can set HTTP cache control headers trivially with `header()`. That said, you could write a preprocessor and run it offline, or use a frontend cache in front of your PHP.

Comment: Just parsing a PHP-script can take milliseconds. If the code has any I/O in it, that could delay it even further. Serving a static file is measured in microseconds. Yes, you aren't going to feel the difference... Until you multiple that time by a few millions.